# Value of protocol type 'InheritingProtocol: Protocol' cannot conform to 'Protocol'

Tags: swift, generics, model-view-controller, protocols, delegation

I have the below code which aims an `abstraction` -without being have to casting `Decodable`s - for `DataModel`s across the app. I wanted use these `DataModel`s to centrelize them. This is how I far I came right now and I am kind of in dead end.

In this configuration, the code tells me that `ProfileResponseDelegate` cannot conform to `ModelDelegate` when `ProfileResponseDelegate` is a `protocol`, which makes sense.

```
protocol ModelDelegate: class {
    
    associatedtype DataType: Decodable
    func didReceive(data: DataType)
    
}

class Model<Type, Delegate: ModelDelegate> where Type == Delegate.DataType {
    
    var data: Type?
    weak var delegate: Delegate?
    
    func requestData() { return }
    
}

protocol ProfileResponseDelegate: ModelDelegate where DataType == ProfileResponse {}

//throws Value of protocol type 'ProfileResponseDelegate' cannot conform to 'ModelDelegate'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
class ProfileResponseModel: Model<ProfileResponse, ProfileResponseDelegate> {
    
    override func requestData() {
        guard let data = data else {
            // go to api to get data
            return
        }
        delegate?.didReceive(data: data)
    }
}

class Controller: UIViewController, ProfileResponseDelegate {
    
    let model = ProfileResponseModel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        model.delegate = self
        model.requestData()
    }
    
    func didReceive(data: ProfileResponse) {
        //tell view code to update regarding data
    }
}
```

When I change `ProfileResponseDelegate` to be a `class` -without not being a `delegate` anymore, but anyway- the code does not allow `Controller` to inherit from both `UIViewController` and `ProfileResponseDelegate` reasoning a `class` cannot inherit from multiple `class`es. which again makes sense.

```
class ProfileResponseDelegate: ModelDelegate {
    typealias DataType = ProfileResponse
    func didReceive(data: ProfileResponse) {
       return
    }
}


class Controller: UIViewController, ProfileResponseDelegate {
    
    let model = ProfileResponseModel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        model.delegate = self
        model.requestData()
    }
    
    override func didReceive(data: ProfileResponse) {
        //tell view code to update regarding data
    }
}
```

With respect to first configuration, I could not make it work. However for the second one, when `Controller` just inherits from `ProfileResponseDelegate` it works just fine.

I have to find a way to make this work -preferably the first configuration- and need your advise. Much appreciated in advance.

**UPDATE**

So I have removed the `associatedType` from the `ModelDelegate` and removed `ProfileResponseModel`. Right now code looks like this.

```
protocol ModelDelegate: class {
    
    //associatedtype DataType: Decodable
    func didReceive<T: Decodable>(data: T)
    
}

class Model<Type: Decodable> {
    
    var data: Type?
    weak var delegate: ModelDelegate?
    
    func requestData() { return }
    
}

//protocol ProfileResponseDelegate: ModelDelegate where DataType == ProfileResponse {}

class ProfileResponseModel: Model<ProfileResponse> {
    
    override func requestData() {
        guard let data = data else {
            // go to api to get data
            return
        }
        delegate?.didReceive(data: data)
    }
}

class Controller: UIViewController, ModelDelegate {
    
    
    let model = ProfileResponseModel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        model.delegate = self
        model.requestData()
    }
    
    func didReceive<T>(data: T) where T : Decodable {
        //I want this `data` to come as what it is.
        if let response = data as? ProfileResponse {
            print(type(of: response))
        }
    }
}
```

It works likes this, however my ultimate purpose for doing this to not being have to cast the `data` to `ProfileResponse` here -and in other places to other `Decodable` type-.

Comment: The first one can never work. That's not what protocols are.

Comment: Any workarounds? @matt

Comment: Pass a completion handler to `requestData()` rather than trying to force a delegate into this. It's totally possible to create a delegate here, but it's overcomplicated for this problem, and a completion handler will dramatically simplify all of it. For a more general approach to the larger problem, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXwJg0QTlZE and for another (even more advanced) approach, see https://davedelong.com/blog/2020/06/27/http-in-swift-part-1/

Comment: Your first approach is actually closer to the goal than your second. In the second, you've said that the delegate has to deal with *any* Decodable that's passed to it. That's the opposite of what you want. Your first approach is technically closer, but making it actually work will put you on the wrong track.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am watching your keynote right now and examined the more advanced implementation. And I got the idea of that maybe I have been wrong starting with API client code. I have written a client much like `Moya` library with generic functions. And for the huge refactoring process that I am in, I try to move as much code as possible away from the View Controllers. I included networking code to this context as well. Purpose of the code above is to provide an interface between Model and Controller and thus there would be a modelController which controls data across the app.

Comment: But from your resources you have shared, I do not need an such interface, I guess?. For example; If I need to share profile data, I fetch the data in ProfileVC and share its necessary variables with detail viewcontrollers and views in the hierarchy. Another concern of mine is using completion blocks inside the either view or controller code. I dont know why but yeah :) Lastly, I have found a way to make above code work but again it did not satisfied me quality wise. Apparently it does not agree with POP already. @RobNapier

Comment: The deeper issue (not related to POP) is that view controllers generally should not create network event directly. This is something we've known in Cocoa, long before Swift. View Controllers should always show the state of a shared Model. VCs can ask the Model to update itself, but they shouldn't generally say "connect to this network service and pass me back the model objects." That doesn't conform to the fact that VCs represent things *on the screen* (and that the user may leave that screen before the update even occurs). So "didReceiveData" should never be in a VC anyway.

Comment: So my intention was right but the solution is not. Can you refer any resource which explains this? with examples. Like I have been looking for a solution -for some time now, did not have any experts around me- to this lack of knowledge of mine through the google searches like "Swift MVC implementation/example". However the results are almost always the same and gives information in broader context. Is there any good resource that really explains the how we should build the relation between controller-view and controller-model -much like your previous referrals-

Comment: I have looked both of your referrals now and I think they mostly focus on network client side. As of my understanding from this thread, there should be another layer between view controller and network client and it is called model. I am looking for how to build that model. This question is that, basically.